# Android Studio classes cannot find inbuilt classes

Tags: android-studio-3.0

Ok, Hello everyone.
So I had posted this problem a week ago, that my Android studio somehow modified the Activity.java
I had been trying to resolve it I had reinstalled Android studio several times. Tried different versions. (Currently I have the stable version of 3.0)
I had been googling all day but hadn’t found any solution. The files were there. In a correct directory, just the other classes could not resolve some of them.
Then I uninstalled the studio once again, manually removed any files in my computer even remotely connected to it and reinstalled. It did work and everything worked for about a week.
Now I got the samo problem with my ListView.java
It marks many of the imports red (the imports are in their correct directories and correctly called).
I have tried the previous solution, but it hasn't helped this time and so if there is anyone who can help me, I would be entirely grateful.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXlhI.png)

Comment: copy and paste the code insted of adding an image of the code, also paste the errors

Comment: I cannot it is too long and there is a mistake on almost every line, but it is a whole ListView class. Original inbuilt one. I changed absolutely nothing in it and the mistakes are not in the code, but the class doesn't create connections to imports which are there. It is the "cannot resolve symbol" type of mistake

Comment: Here is a link to the code:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/ListView.java